# Is Google GPU beta available in free trial?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using google free trial of $300. Recently tried to launch a GPU instance as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus?authuser=3).

I have configured the right region. But the message is "**Quota 'NVIDIA_K80_GPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0**". Does this mean that GPU is not available in free trial? Or is it somekind of error from gcp.

Comment: You can't attach GPUs to preemptible instances and GPUs do not receive sustained use discounts so I think it's almost certainly the case that GPUs are simply not available in the free trial.

Comment: I was on the free trial but upgraded my account. I created a new project to see if it would be any different but it looks like the my quota for GPUs is still 0. There's a form to request an increase for quotas -- see the [Requesting additional quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas?hl=en_US#requesting_additional_quota) docs. I thought that upgrading my account to a paid account would do the trick but it did not.

Comment: Google says  "You can't request an increase until you upgrade your free trial account"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the quota is zero for every one. One need to request for additional quota if he needs to increase the GPU. This form is only available if we upgrade our account. In the increase quota form it says "**Please note that projects using free trial credits are not eligible for quota increases until the free trial period has ended.**"

**Update**

The google GPU is no more in beta and is shown available in free trial.But you can't start the machine in free trial mode as the quota is 0.
[Refer for information on regions and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/)

Comment: So How to upgrade a free trial account?

Comment: @ShuangSong select free trial status and click upgrade

Comment: Even after upgrading, quota is zero. Do we have to manually send a request to increase GPU quota ?

Comment: "If GPUs are not listed on the quotas page or you require additional GPU quota, request a quota increase. If your project has an established billing history, it will receive quota automatically after you submit the request. Free Trial accounts do not receive GPU quota by default"- Google. I think you need to upgrade.

Comment: "Please wait two business days..." They're crazy.

Comment: should be noted that even your account is upgraded,  you might not be approved for the quota request if you still have some remaining free-credit .

Comment: This feels deceptive of google