# Can not create Jupyter notebook instance in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gpu, quota

I am trying to [create](https://console.cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/create-instance) a simple Jupyter notebook in Google Cloud Platform with GPU:

- Name: PyTorch
- Region: us-west1 (Oregon)
- Zone: us-west1-b
- Operating System" Debain 9
- Environment: PyTorch 1.4 (with Intel (R) MKL-DNN/MKL)
- Machine type: n1-standard-4 (4vCPUs, 15GB RAM)
- GPU type: NVIDIA Tesla K80
- Number of GPUs: 1
- Install NVIDIA GPU driver automatically for me
- Boot disk type: Standard Persistent Disk
- Boot disk size in GB: 100
- Data disk type: Standard Persistent Disk
- Data disk size in GB: 100
- Google-managed-key
- Network: default
- Subnetwork: default
- External IP (Automatic)
- Access to JupyterLab (Service account)
- Use Compute Engine default service account

After I press "Create" it returns to a [list of instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/list/instances). It shows loading and after I refresh disappears. When I create a Jupiter notebook without GPU it succeeds. My guess is that I need to request a GPU quota. For this, I go to [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) page and see that Compute Engine API for NVIDIA K80 GPUs is "1 of 24 quotas are reaching limit". When I press all quotes, I see that Current Usage is 0 for everyone 7-day peak usage is 1 fo for us-west1 and Limit is 1. I can not select any checkbox.

How can I resolve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit your quota, you must have the serviceusage.quotas.update permission, which is by default in: Owner, Editor, and Quota Administrator roles. If that's set, I may ask a stupid question, but is your account a premium one? As far as I know, you cannot modify quotas on a free trial account.

Comment: I believe I am the owner (I see it at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin). However, I think I do use a free trial with credits. I am not sure if I need to modify the quota. I only need 1 GPU, is it included in the default quota? Thanks!

Comment: I see, in this case I don't think it's possible as per their page: https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas 

"If you're using the Google Cloud free trial, you can't request a change to your quota."

Also, according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423912/is-google-gpu-beta-available-in-free-trial you cannot use GPU's in free trial, even if you have credits. Couldn't find the google doc official page though.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like. a good reason to move back to AWS :) Especially annoying is the fact that UI shows 1 quota...